# How to Impersonate User via System Account

Tags: c#, impersonation

I am working on desktop application using C# (Windows service) in which I am trying to Impersonate User
via system space. I tried retrieving user token by triggering new process but it is still running in 
system account. Is there ant way to Impersonate User via system account?

Comment: Can you try rephrasing your question to make it clearer? You've got "desktop application", "Windows service" and something you call "system space" all in the same sentence. Start by saying what kind of application you are writing, what account the app will be running under, what account you are trying to impersonate (and why). Where you expect to get the token from, etc. Show the code you've been using (working or not) as an [mcve]